# How to Get any kind of Response in Intent.ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to User to share my app Link or any text, without sharing he cannot proceed further (Or at least open the app and came back).

by `Intent.ACTION_SEND` I can send him to another app but I don't know when he is coming back to my app.

I want to know any kind of response that tells me he is back to my app and then i will proceed him further.

**This is my code**

```
val intentShare:Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intentShare.setType("text/plane")
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Your Subject")
intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This the text to Send")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare,"Select your App"))
```

I have Tried OnActivity Result but the control never comes here , as i have read somewhere  that `Intent.ACTION_SEND` Does not return any data.

please tell me a way.

Comment: For onActivityResult to trigger you need to start with startActivityForResult at least.

Comment: @blackapps I did the same but it doesn't work as expected. I want to know weather user select any app or he just cancels that select app dialog screen. By you method weather he cancels or do anything i get result code as -1

Comment: are you sure that is even possible ? as far as i know, there is no way of knowing what a user did, the best you can do is show the prompt to share, but that's as far as it goes

Comment: @a_local_nobody I also think think that but is there a work around??

Comment: Email clients dont have to return anything. There is no documentation that implies they should. Further i understand what you want. You are not alone ;-) I think there are email apps that send a response.